# Image on top of uiTableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

Im little lost here,thats what i need to do:

[image: Exampple]

But the tableview seems to take all the view and the image just gone...its possible to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Use a UIView, put your UIImageView on the top, tableview at the bottom inside the UIView.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.

Looking at your attached screenshot, it looks like you have the gist of it. That said, your question is quite vague without further details it will be unlikely people will be able to address your problem